# django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution. Django for professionals book

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

These are my docker files getting this error while changing my engine from SQLite to PostgreSQL. Doing it for the first time following book called Django for professionals
docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
    - .:/code
    ports:
    - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
    - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9.6

#set environment variables

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

#set work directory
WORKDIR /code

#install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

Comment: hi, have you tried adding `ports` to `db` as you did  on `web`? for example, `ports:
      - 5432:5432`

Comment: yes i have port 5432 in my settings.py file

Comment: oh, i meant `ports` parameter in `docker-compose.yml`. from what you posted, your `db` does not have `ports`.

Comment: no I'm not using any port parameters in db. but that worked for me.

Comment: What command are you running that produces that error?  What's the `CMD` the Docker image should normally run?

Comment: ```docker-compose up -d --build```

Answer (score 1):

as suggested by seoul kim above i added `ports: -5432:5432` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

hello i think that your problem is in the setting.py and in dtabases change the db to local host or 127.0.0.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).